# Extract n rows of a 1 dimensional numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix of size (50,). How do I obtain the first n items of this matrix?

If I had a (50,50) matrix, M, I could do something like

```
M[5:,:]
```

to get the first 5 rows. However, I am unsure of how to do this for 1 dimension.

Comment: How bout `M[:5]`?

Comment: Yes! Sorry I should have figured this out!

Answer (score 2):

It would simply be  `M[:5]` as [@Ashumaan Mishra said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71630406/extract-n-rows-of-a-1-dimensional-numpy-matrix#comment126595523_71630406)!